# Was bedeutet das Verb “instagrammen”?

Tags: meaning, verb

Ich lese die folgende Webseite:

http://www.bento.de/gadgets/bundeswehr-auf-instagram-09808/

Was bedeutet das im Titel genannte Verb *instagrammen*?

Comment: Instagram benutzen. Vergleiche englisch *to instagram* oder *skypen* (*to skype*). Natürlich ist der Titel auch ein Wortwitz zur Bundeswehrwerbung »Wir. Dienen. Deutschland.«

Comment: Sag bloß? Wir. Sind. Baff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **googeln**
  Google benutzen
  etwas mit der Suchmaschine Google suchen
- **skypen**
  Skype benutzen
  sich mit jemanden mit Hilfe des Messengers Skype unterhalten
- **twittern**
  Twitter benutzen
  Nachrichten mit dem Kurznachrichtendienst Twitter versenden
- **facebooken**
  Facebook benutzen
  Mitteilungen auf dem sozialen Medium Facebook teilen
- **facetimen**
  Facetime benutzen
  sich mit jemanden mit Hilfe des Messengers Facetime unterhalten

und nach genau demselben Schema:

- **instagrammen**
  Instagram benutzen
  Bilder auf der Foto- und Video-Plattform Instagram teilen

Bei diesem Wortschöpfungen wird ganz einfach der Markenname in ein Verb umgewandelt, und das so gebildete Verb bedeutet: Den jeweiligen Online-Dienst in Anspruch nehmen.